# go select with <-time.After(duration) first time instant

Tags: go

at the moment I am using a for loop like this

```
for ; true; <-time.After(duration)
```

the first time it is executed instantly, then by <-time.After(duration)

Now I need to rewrite this function so that I can
stop it with a channel. By default, this is done using select, but it waits for the <-time.After(duration) already at the first iteration

```
for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case t := <-time.After(duration):
        fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
    }
}
```

how i can solve it?

Comment: Something like this https://go.dev/play/p/6ruCT0q1ssF? Btw. what is "unsanate"?

Comment: @mkopriva just stop, T9

Comment: You could also just keep the original for loop and at the top of its body have a `select` on the `done` channel with a `default` case that is empty, e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/3QuY40ikkKn

Comment: Would you be able to add the full sample adding how you are triggering the mentioned selection block and how you are sending messages over the `done` channel?

Comment: @tmarwen for what? I can't show this. it has to do with a different logic. mkopriva has already given a good option

Comment: @mkopriva although this is not really a good option, because if I first stop the function and then start it again, the first function will still be waiting for <-time.after and the second instance will immediately exit

Comment: @ERVIN228 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by stop then. If `case <-done:` is hit, the `return` statement is executed, once the function returns it's not gonna do anything else, it's not gonna wait on anything else (other then any deferred statemnts), it simply exits and is removed from the stack.

Comment: @mkopriva done is not a context, but just chan struct{}, on a certain event, I want to stop this function and send struct{}{} to this channel. But then I can just run it again with go. if duration is large, then it turns out that the second instance of the function will stop, and the first one will continue to work

Comment: @ERVIN228 I did not say nor imply that done is a context, it clearly isn't since you're doing the receive operation on it and you cannot receive from a context instance. Furthermore I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to explain, it would be much easier if you provide a [mcve]. Show the code, show the problem. Not in the comments, but in the question, this one or a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` statement will cycle through the different `channel`s checking **one by one** if the channel is ready for *read* or *write*.

In case no channel is ready for *read* or *write*, the `select` statement will block waiting for one of the `channel`s readiness **unless** there is a `default` statement which in your case should be a *no-op*:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case t := <-time.After(duration):
        fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
    default: // cycle back
    }
}
```

Comment: You never want a `default` in an empty for+select like that, because you have turned it into a busy loop, are defeating the purpose of the `time.After`, and will quickly overwhelm the scheduler and gc.

Comment: I totally agree and I would not implement such a logic myself as it totally collapses the purpose of `time.After`. My point was to adapt the main author snippet with proper explanation.